# How to use variable from CSV in multiple object instances in Adobe Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator

Can any help me shed some light on why I cant seem to us a single variable from a CSV file and link it to multiple text string objects?

I've made a video showing you exactly what I'm doing... https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1TX4TrC8glI

So I make text objects and select them both...

[image]

I then go to the variables panel and click the **Make Text Dynamic** button...

[image]

I then rename both variables to `job_number`

[image]

I then create my CSV file...

[image]

I then load the CSV file by selecting **Load Variable Library** from the Menu...

[image]

I then get this dialog to which I click **Yes**...

[image]

Which then shows this **ERROR** dialog!

[image]

What am I doing so wrong here? Makes no sense.

Any help would be much appreciated thanks!

Comment: You shouldn't cross post on Stack OverFlow and here. It would be better to edit your question there to provide more information. To be honest with you, tech support is off-topic here anyway. If you think there's a bug, you should contact Adobe.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm having the same issue...

Comment: no I don't think I ever did, gave up on the idea of using the same variable in multiple instances in illustrator. I posted this on Adobe too but didn't get very far... https://community.adobe.com/t5/illustrator-discussions/filter-error-when-using-variable-on-multiple-objects/m-p/13259037 ...let me know if you crack the problem!